# add Twitter Cards in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I am trying add twitter cards to my wordpress blog, I used Yoast SEO plugin and filled it's configrations...
this tutorial help me to do that
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-twitter-cards-in-wordpress/ .
the proplem is that I must  valid my link by https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator so that the image and discriptions apear instead of the link when paste my article link to tweet it.

Comment: Did you follow this procedure by Yoast? https://kb.yoast.com/kb/setting-up-twitter-cards-in-wordpress-seo/

Comment: Yes i follow all steps by yoast